# How to use fetch sent the Data URI from canvas to google sheet

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sent the image as base64 code to google sheet by using `fetch`,but when I run my code it will shows error "data_sent is not defined".

I want to know where is the problem and how to fix it.

*image is the variable to save the image builded by canvas, image_data is the variable to save the base64 from image

```js
this.saveAsImg = function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    if (image.src == this.emptyCanvas) {
        alert('請先書寫')
    } else {
        console.log('提交的內容===>', image.src)
    }
    return image.src;
};
var image_data;

document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
    image_data = writeCanvas.saveAsImg();
};

function post_trigger(image_data, uuid) {
    let url = 'localhost:5050';
    let data_sent = image_data;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: data_sent
                //deviceID: uuid
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((jsonData) => {
        console.log(jsonData);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('錯誤:', err);
    })
}
document.getElementById('save').onclick = post_trigger(image, uuid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code and here is the new code. It can connect to api and post Data URI successfully.

```js
let post_trigger = document.getElementById('sent');

    post_trigger.addEventListener('click', async function() {
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2';
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("email", str);
        let result = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                uri: str
            }),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(res => {
            return res.text();
        })
        alert(result);
    })
```